# What does "do something to the good part" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have come across this phrase in the TV show *Friends*. It was in the 17th episod of the third season. The context is Chandler really wants to smoke, but he can't because the lighter is in the car which they can't open because the keys are inside. And when they finally open Chandler jums in and says

> At least let me smoke it **to the good part**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4T_Ox5J-C0) of that moment in the episode on YouTube. Chandler is asking for permission to smoke in the car (other people in the car may not enjoy cigarette smoke). The "it" refers to the cigarette he has just lit, and in my interpretation, the "good part" of the cigarette is the part where he starts to feel the effect of the nicotine.

If I'm right, then this sentence could be rephrased as:

> At least let me smoke this cigarette until I can feel its effects.

It is implied that Chandler doesn't find a cigarette enjoyable right away, and so he's asking his friends to let him smoke in the car long enough that it can become enjoyable.